# Trying to achieve a "Garage Door" Effect with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm building a fairly simple site with just a header centered on the top that sits over a full screen image. Behind the image is a full screen Vimeo video. My goal is to have it so that when I scroll, the image moves up and off the screen to reveal the video behind it, and then continue normal scrolling to any elements below the video. I'm newer to WebDev so I'm really just looking for a place to start. I'm fooling around with some positioning and transtionZ CSS etc. but I can't get it to work.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/GarageDoorMenu/

Comment: That requires me to set the video as the background though. I'd like for there to be able to be content after the video.